# Get a list of names used in a list of Person objects

Tags: c#, list

Say, I have a Person object list called people:

```
public class Person
{
    public int age;
    public string name;

    public Person(int age, string name)
    {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

The list is populated with a large amount of people data. How do I get a list of all the names used in the list, but only one occurrence for each name? For example, if in the people List there are 1000 people with the firstname 'Bob' and 200000 with the firstname 'Alice', my list should contain only one entry for 'Bob' and one entry for 'Alice'.

Comment: If this list of people is populated from a database, consider using the database to give you a list of distinct names if that's all you need in your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're able to use LINQ, it's as easy as:

```
var distinctNames = people.Select(p => p.name).Distinct();
```

If not, it's a little bit more complicated:

```
var distinctNames = new List<string>();

foreach(var person in people)
    if(!distinctNames.Contains(person.Name)) distinctNames.Add(person.Name);
```

Or, if you're working with large data sets and need something more efficient (at the cost of space):

```
var distinctNames = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(var person in people)
{
    if(!distinctNames.ContainsKey(person.Name))
    {
        distinctNames.Add(person.Name, person.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're not able to use LINQ, you're not able to use `HashSet<T>` either.

Comment: @Slaks - Went the more pedestrian route using `List<T>` instead.

Comment: @Jason: True.  (lathough note LINQBridge)

Comment: That's O(n^2).  You can bring it back down to O(n) by using a dictionary, or by stealing Mono's HashSet.

Answer (score 6):

```
var names = people.Select(p => p.name).Distinct();
```